# DbFit exception using SQL server 2008

Tags: .net, fitsharp, dbfit

New to dbFit. Downloaded version dbfit 1.1 which successful executed the queries, except for one query. That query would then timeout.

When I then update with fixes for the timeout - https://github.com/jediwhale/fitsharp, will fail.

Then returns the following error:

```
    System.ApplicationException: Type 'dbfit.sqlserver' could not be found in  assemblies.
   Assemblies searched:    file:///C:/fitnesse20090321/fitnesse/dotnet/FitLibrary.DLL
file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
file:///C:/fitnesse20090321/fitnesse/dotnet/FitServer.exe
file:///C:/fitnesse20090321/fitnesse/dotnet/fit.DLL
file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
         file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/System.Web/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll
      Load errors: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\fitnesse20090321\fitnesse\dotnet\dbfit.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded., Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\fitnesse20090321\fitnesse\dotnet\dbfit.sqlserver.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded., Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\fitnesse20090321\fitnesse\dotnet\dbfit.sybase.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded., Could not load file or assembly           'file:///C:\fitnesse20090321\fitnesse\dotnet\fitSharp.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded., Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\fitnesse20090321\fitnesse\classes' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified., Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\fitnesse20090321\fitnesse\fitnesse.jar' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
  at fit.Assemblies.FindType(TypeName theName)
  at fit.TypeName.get_Type()
 at fit.TypeName.CreateInstance()
  at fit.Fixture.LoadClass(String theClassName)
  at fit.StoryTest.DoTables()
```

Any ideas as to the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Which download did you get? It sounds like you downloaded a zip file for a different version of the .Net Framework that what the other software is using (so 4.0 instead of 2.0 maybe.)